# hdwallet-provider set multiple account addresses when deploy contract

Tags: web3js, metamask, hdwalletprovider

I'm using for deploying contracts hdwallet-provider, but I have issue on client side to get multiple accounts using web3.eth.getAccounts() call.

I know this is like duplicate question and truffle already has solution for this, but I have issue getting more than one account address.

On metamask I have three accounts, but only the default one is showing on the client side.
From the first snippet u can see that I'm setting 3 as fourth parametar

Deploy code

```
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  'mnemonic....',
  'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/bba91a6c349c44afbde264a1bda1af75', 0, 3
);
```

How I import web3 in client code

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

if (window.ethereum) {
  window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

  (async () => {
    await window.ethereum.enable();
  })();
}
// Legacy dapp browsers...
else if (window.web3) {
  window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
}
// Non-dapp browsers...
else {
  console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
}

export default window.web3;
```

Client code

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log);
```

BR, Igor

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior that you will get the only account selected in the Metamask. This is for privacy reasons.

Metamsk even don't expose one account be default, Dapps need to send an access request to the account by calling `ethereum.enable()`. Dapps will get the access to the selected metamask account once the acces request is approved by user.

You can read more about in [this](https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8) blog post.

Comment: Thanks. My concern was, how I get current account address, but I can use web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress